# Mongoose with JSON Data having values as property names

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a json object in the format  -

```
{
  'Which is the Capital of India ? ': {
      'Delhi': 1,
      'Bangalore': 0,
      'Mumbai': 0,
      'Chennai': 0
  }
}
```

And I am trying to write the schema in mongoose for this object. I have written -

```
exports.quiz = mongoose.Schema({
   question: {
       answer: Boolean
   }
});
```

Since I am a mongodb and mongoose newbie, I need to know whether is this the right approach?

Comment: you would need to call `.model()` at some point http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html

Comment: Yes I am aware of that, I call that in my route(I am using express). But is the schema declaration correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a very good representation for an object. Think of an "Object" as a generic form of container for your data. All of the "keys" you specify in your JSON form are actually "data" points, and should be treated as such.

Also, for best performance you want this to be embedded data, since in that way there are singular reads and writes to MongoDB. Which is why you should be using MongoDB, and not trying to model this in a relational way.

So a good form of generic schema would be like this:

```
// Initial requires
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// A generic answer sub-schema
var answerSchema = new Schema({
    answer: String,
    correct: Boolean
});

// A generic Question schema
var  questionSchema = new Schema({
    text: String,
    answers: [answerSchema]
});

exports.Question = mongoose.model( 'Question', questionSchema );
```

The serialized form in MongoDB then comes out to basically this:

```
{
    "text": "Which is the Capital of India",
    "answers": [
        { "answer": "Delhi", "correct": true },
        { "answer": "Bangalore", "correct": false },
        { "answer": "Mumbai", "correct": false },
        { "answer": "Chennai", "correct":  false }         
    ]
}
```

Transforming from your current JSON is not an issue:

```
var orig; // Your existing structure
var data = {};

Object.keys(orig).forEach(function(title) {
    // Really only expecting one top level key here

    // Stripping out the common formatting
    var fixed = title.replace(/\s+\?\s+$/,"");

    data.text = fixed;
    data.answers = [];

    // Loop the answer keys
    Object.keys(orig[title]).forEach(function(answer) {
        data.answers.push({
            answer: answer,
            correct: (orig[title][answer]) ? true : false
        });
    });
    Question.create( data, function(err,question) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("Created: %s", question );
    });
});
```

But look into async loop control for a better way to to this with a bulk list of "questions".

So the generic structure gives you some nice options:

- You can add some formatting logic inherent to the schema object, such as formatting the question in a consistent way. Since we stripped off the trailing whitespace and "?" question mark. Removed from your data this can be added in via methods and custom serialization.
- Answers is an array so you could "shuffle" the order so the possible answers don't always appear in the same order.

Another neat thing with the embedded array items (and especially considering the last point) is that mongoose by default will assign a unique `_id` field to each array element. This makes checking answers easy:

```
Question.findOne(
    { 
        "_id": questionId,
        "answers": { "$elemMatch": { "_id": anwerId, "correct": true } }
    },
    function(err,result) {
      if (err); // handle hard errors

      if (result != null) {
         // correct
      } else {
         // did not match, so got it wrong
      }
    }
);
```

And that is the meat of a "generic" server side response handler, which essentially requires two parameters in the payload, being the current `questionId` and the submitted `answerId`. When the result of a `.findOne()` operation does not match a document and the response is `null` then the answer was incorrect.

This means you can add more "sugar" in your schema definitions. A little "brute force" here (but for example) and you can remove the "correct" keys from the answers sent to the client and do some other formatting as well. After the main schema definitions:

```
// Fisher Yates shuffle
function shuffle(array) {
  var counter = array.length,
      temp,
      index;

  while (counter > 0) {
    index = Math.floor(Math.random() * counter);

    counter--;

    temp = array[counter];
    array[counter] = array[index];
    array[index] = temp;
  }

  return array;
}

if (!answerSchema.options.toJSON) answerSchema.options.toJSON = {};
answerSchema.options.toJSON.transform = function(doc,ret,opts) {
  // Pulling the "correct" markers from the client response
  delete ret.correct;
};


if (!questionSchema.options.toJSON) questionSchema.options.toJSON = {};
questionSchema.options.toJSON.transform = function(doc,ret,opts) {

  // Add the formatting back in
  if ( ret.hasOwnProperty('text') )
    ret.text = doc.text + " ? ";

  // Shuffle the anwers
  ret.answers = shuffle(doc.answers);
};

exports.Question = mongoose.model( 'Question', questionSchema );
```

This gives you a nice packaged and "hidden data" response to send to the client for display:

```
{
  "text": "Which is the Capital of India ? ",
  "_id": "5450b0d49168d6dc1dbf866a",
  "answers": [
    {
      "answer": "Delhi",
      "_id": "5450b0d49168d6dc1dbf866e"
    },
    {
      "answer": "Chennai",
      "_id": "5450b0d49168d6dc1dbf866b"
    },
    {
      "answer": "Bangalore",
      "_id": "5450b0d49168d6dc1dbf866d"
    },
    {
      "answer": "Mumbai",
      "_id": "5450b0d49168d6dc1dbf866c"
    }
  ]
}
```

So overall:

- Better ways to model for MongoDB
- Simple one query read and response checking
- Hide the data from the client with custom serialize logic.

A few nice things you can do that scale well and put the logic where it is needed.

Comment: How do I design the form to save this type of nested data.
Please have a look at my other question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26650304/save-design-nested-form-to-save-update-data-in-mongodb-via-mongoose-according-to

Many thanks for your help